# Computing N cofactors

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

I have an $N\times N$ matrix of small size (say $N=20$). Is there a way to evaluate the $N$ cofactors of the elements of the first row, faster than in the obvious way as $N$ independent determinant computations, involving $O(N^4)$ operations ?

For instance, can we exploit Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting or Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization to get them in a single go ?

Comment: A minor of a matrix involves removal of a row and a column, so they would be size $(N-1)\times(N-2)$. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @VictorLiu Rephrased.

Comment: I think we can get away with two Gaussian eliminations (or variants thereof). Let's call your matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{N\times N}.$ Then, by [Cramer's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule), the first column of $A^{-1}$ is given by the cofactors of the first row of $A$ divided by $\det A.$ We can get the first column of $A^{-1}$ by solving the inhomogeneous system $e_1 = Ax$ for $x \in \mathbb R^N,$ where $e_1 \in \mathbb R^N$ is the first "standard" basis vector. This is one Gaussian elimination.

Comment: [continued] We can compute $\det A$ by bringing $A$ into triangular form using another Gaussian elimination. Now, if we multiply the solution vector $x$ from above with $\det A,$ we get the cofactors of the first row of $A.$ Since one Gaussian elimination uses $O(N^3)$ operations, the whole procedure described in my comments also uses $O(N^3)$ operations.

Comment: @jflipp: yep, I found another Mathematics post about computing the first row of a matrix inverse (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952870/finding-only-first-row-in-a-matrix-inverse), which is what you suggest. Thanks. Actually, I don't have the coefficients of the first row, so they can be supplied arbitrarily; I think we can also perform Gaussian elimination on all but the first row, and supply $0,0,0\cdots,1$ in the end.